# DocuSign Integrator Key is not found or disabled

Tags: docusignapi

I created a new developer account on DocuSign, generated the integrator key. Now i am trying to submit a GET request for retrieving account information but I keep getting error message "Integrator key is not found or disabled"
Below is my request which I am submitting using fiddler"service integration authentication" :

Raw http request

```
GET https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information HTTP/1.1
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username": "MyEmail","Password": "MyPassword","IntegratorKey": "IntegratorKeyCreatedFromAdminConsole"}
Host: www.docusign.net
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 128
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 4694b892-09cb-41aa-b5fa-307d226e9dd0
Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 16:26:33 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

{
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled."
}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 9):

The URL you are trying to access is a production URL. Your integrator key only exists in DEMO, so update the URL to:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign should update their documentation at https://docs.docusign.com/esign/  When they talk about getting the baseURL they specify to go to the production url.  They don't mention they have a URL for their demo system.  Also their CURL sample does not work for DOS CURL.  One has to use `"` and escape the json `"` with `\` for example

`curl -H "X-DocuSign-Authentication:{\"Username\": \"bob@example.com\",\"Password\": \"xxx\",\"IntegratorKey\": \"your_key\"}" https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information`

Comment: hey IAmCoder, you said DOS CURL, as in MS-DOS ?